# Precompile Assets in Production of Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

But I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
```

However, there is nothing in the production group of my database configuration file, because I use Heroku, which doesn't require it be set up.

Comment: so, just add one. ie the development or test setup.

Comment: Is it okay to copy and paste exactly what the test set up has including the database name?

Comment: you can delete it right after you created the assets. I assume you are just testing the precompilation step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy your development configuration and label it production, it should work. Since heroku overrides it, if present, you won't cause any issues and you'll be able to precompile locally.

like so...

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  encoding: unicode
  database: yourapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: yourapp
  password:

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  encoding: unicode
  database: yourapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: yourapp
  password:
```